# SQL Server CTE - recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have 2 tables, first contains data of documents and second for directories.

Table 1

```
DocID  DirID  Name  Order
-----  -----  ----  -----
1      4      Doc1  2
2      1      Doc2  1
3      5      Doc3  1
4      3      Doc4  1
5      4      Doc5  1
```

Table 2

```
DirID  ParentID  Name
-----  --------  ----
1      NULL      root
2      1         Dir1
3      2         Dir2
4      1         Dir3
5      3         Dir4
```

Structure

```
root
-Dir1
 -Dir2
  -Dir4
   -Doc3 
  -Doc4 
-Dir3
 -Doc5 
 -Doc1 
-Doc2
```

I'm trying to create CTE in T-SQL, which will generate this result, but I can't figure out how to do it. Can somebody suggest a solution?

```
Doc2
Dir3/Doc5
Dir3/Doc1
Dir1/Dir2/Doc4
Dir1/Dir2/Dir4/Doc3
```

Root is not shown, documents are sorted by `Order` within its directory and the result is sorted from the lowest depth ordered by name of full path.

Comment: Show you query, what did you tried?

Comment: Note `order` column name is a [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) careful with syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CTE` for generating folder hierarchy
Then join documents to the folders
And order result using created `Path` for that purpose

```
DECLARE @Separator AS VARCHAR(1) = '\\'
--Generating folder hierarchy
;WITH Info AS
(
    SELECT f.DirID
    , f.ParentID
    , f.Name
    , CAST(f.Name AS VARCHAR(255)) AS PathValue
    FROM Folders f
    WHERE f.ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT f.DirID
    , f.ParentID
    , f.Name
    , CAST(i.PathValue + @Separator + f.Name AS VARCHAR(255))
    FROM Folders f
    INNER JOIN Info i ON f.ParentID = i.DirID
)

-- Join documents to the folder hirarchy
SELECT i.ParentID
, i.DirID
, i.Name
, d.DocID
, d.Name
, i.PathValue + @Separator + CAST(d.OrderNum AS VARCHAR(255)) + '.' + d.Name AS OrderPath
, i.PathValue + @Separator + d.Name AS DocumentPath
FROM Info i
INNER JOIN Documents d ON d.DirID = i.DirID

UNION ALL

-- Adding NULL row for folder, will show folder in the result even no documents
-- This can be removed if you want show only folders which containing documents
SELECT i.ParentID
, i.DirID
, i.Name
, NULL
, NULL
, i.PathValue AS OrderPath
, i.PathValue AS DocumentPath
FROM Info i
ORDER BY OrderPath
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b9e33/1)

Answer (score 2):

Using `Recursive CTE`, you could easily create a path as shown above:

**NOTE**: I believe your output is wrong for **Doc4**: `Dir1/Dir2/Doc4`. It should be `Dir1/Doc4` per logic.

```
;WITH q1
AS (
    SELECT a.DocID
        ,b.*
        ,a.NAME AS rootname
    FROM tableb b
    LEFT JOIN tablea a ON b.DirID = a.DirID
    )
,q2
AS (
    -- anchor 
    SELECT DocID
        ,DirID
        ,q1.rootname
        ,ParentID
        ,CAST((q1.NAME) AS VARCHAR(1000)) [Path]
    FROM q1
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    --recursive member 
    SELECT t.DocID
        ,t.DirID
        ,t.rootname
        ,t.ParentID
        ,CAST((a.path + '/' + t.NAME) AS VARCHAR(1000)) [Path]
    FROM q1 AS t
    INNER JOIN q2 AS a ON t.ParentId = a.DirID
    )
SELECT replace([Path] + '/' + q2.rootname, 'root/', '') AS FinalPath
FROM q2
WHERE q2.rootname IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY FinalPath DESC
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/06258/1)

Comment: Sorry for late response, I just went through some older questions and I missed this one. If I remember well, the second answer is longer, but it seemed clearer to me, but both work.